# Console in VS 2012 Express for C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, console, eclipse-cdt

I'm very new to programming, so be nice.

I was using Eclipse for C/C++ devs for a while, but it seemed quite buggy so I was advised to switch to Visual Studio Express. I'm just testing out with a simple "Hello World" program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    string response;
    cout << "Gimme a string: " << flush;
    cin >> response;
    cout << "The string is: " << response << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

not much to go wrong there

anyway, I noticed that there is no "console" like in Eclipse. All of the text pops up in a little command prompt window. And, also, this window closes right after displaying new text if there is no other things to do after it (like a `cin`). I have been told that I can use system("pause") but there has to be a better way. In Eclipse, the text would not suddenly disappear because the console window closed.

i know this question might be a little confusing, comment and I'll try to explain what I'm saying.
Or paste the codes into your Visual Studio 2012 Express Edition.

But is there a way to display all of my text and whatever in a "console" as opposed to a command prompt-type window; and why does it always close before I can read the last thing?

Comment: you can also open a console (cmd) by your own and navigate to the path you are working on. this one wouldn't close after your program is terminated.

Comment: I always just put a breakpoint on the `return` in `main`. There's not much you can do otherwise, that's just the way Windows works and VS doesn't do anything to get around it.

Comment: I used to have old visual studio, they were pause by default, however, not sure which version, probably around 2008, the console disappear without knowing what output we got, so I tried system("pause");, or sometime getchar() function call which wait for a key to proceed

Answer (score 2):

1. right click your project name,
2. go to Properties page
3. expand Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System
4. select Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE) in SubSystem dropdown

Comment: Having set it up as abdul recomends, notice that Ctr+F5 with wait for a key input to actually close the window, but it will run without debugging. With the mentioned settings, you should be able to visualize the console almost on every version of VStudios (from 2008 to 2012 IIRC)

Comment: @notNullGothik sorry, that was a little confusing. If you use Ctrl-F5 then it just runs the program, as opposed to debugging? If this **is** what you mean, then is there a way to put a "run" button on the ribbon that you can click instead of the "debug" button?

Comment: @abdul I did this, but it didn't seem to make a difference. Where is the console supposed to appear?

Comment: @notNullGothik I tried your idea and it worked! Thanks so much! I assume you have to close it by manually pressing the 'x'. Or maybe Alt-F4 or something

Comment: @Live2Code am glad it worked, there was a minor typo on the comment (said Crtl+F5 will wait for a key), anyways I don't see how the instructions adbul wrote didn't work, it should! (don't forget to up vote useful comments)

Comment: @Live2Code the console window will wait until a key is pressed, it can be x or whatever you like. Alt-F4 will work as well, but that should be due to the OS shortcuts (am not sure), not related to a VStudio setting

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you describe is how Visual Studio works by default, and to be honest I have always found it a little strange.  In debug mode I add a break point to the return line at the end of my program if I want the window to hang around and see what happened.  Else I would be running my release program from a command prompt directly so it isn't a problem.  I've never found a way to change the behaviour to a docked panel which I what I would prefer - maybe someone else knows?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, there is a function to output to the debug console:
[OutputDebugStringA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
I have not tried it in the Express versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [OutputDebugString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method. I might suggest making your own wrapper class that uses the OutputDebugStream as its source but resembles stdio. Its a pain and I am not sure why Visual Studio doesn't help with standard I/O to a console functionality. There are probably some open source projects out there that have already done this for you. A brief search and I found [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27952/Debug-logging-with-STL-stream-operators).